# Using the $.ajax() with different directories?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I use the '$.ajax()' technique, to provide the url parameter with a location outside the project(let's say the file is on the desktop). How can i do that ?? I know how to do it only in the same location of the project..

Thanks alot

Comment: The desktop??? You mean on the user's computer? You can't - horrible security issues if you could. Unless I've misinterpreted what you mean

Comment: I don't know if you'd be allowed to access the desktop. Certainly if you want to talk to a different web host you'll need to look into cross-domain restrictions e.g. the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers

Comment: Let me see if I understood... You want, via AJAX, to perform a request to you local system file? If you do, I'm not quite sure if this is possible... It seems to be a security breach. If you want to upload a file via AJAX you have several plugins that already do this.

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have? That might help clarify your question.

Comment: @Miguel Ribeiro, yes this is what i need.. it seems that i will do virtual directory.

Comment: Thank u so much Guys.... the virtual directory did the job for me;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not bypass the website and access the files out side it as it could harm the machine hosting the website, but you can access files outside the website through you website.

1. You can access the files within the website folder or you can make virtual directory of 
   folders outside you website folder and access it through virtual directory.

Suppose you have website folder d:\websites\TestWebsite and you want to access files within d:\Data\Testfile.txt, make a virtual directory in side TestWebsite pointing to d:\Data and access files within it through virual directory.

2  You can also make a function that lies in some webpage/webservice and access the files outside the website.

Comment: Thank u so much. the virtual directory did the job for me;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do ajax request to local files for security reasons, they have to be at the reach of your local server, alias the 'public directory'.

**EDIT:** Apart from the virtual directories solution at server configuration level as Adil suggest, you can do it simpler by using symbolic links from your files or directories to your public folder.

Comment: DannYO, the file that i need to access it is on the server itself but in different directory. this is what i need... It seems that i will use virtual directory, & i will search for how to implement it & access it with the ajax

Comment: if it is in the server it should work, it should be where your index file is or any other sub directory. Your index -> /public/dir/path/index.xyz . Your file -> /public/dir/path/mydir/myfile.xyz . And the url you call -> http://localhost/mydir/myfile.xyz